# App sigue deteniendose (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Buen día, tengo un soporte de una aplicación android que originalmente fue desarrollada en API 27 en el 2018. Desafortunadamente, el archivo del proyecto le faltan datos, por lo que he ido completando los datos de acuerdo a como se me van presentando los errores.

[image: Aplicación keeps stopping]

Actualmente la aplicación ya se construye con éxito, sin embargo no abre en mi emulador. he observado en el logcat en el preciso momento en que hay un Fatal Exception, pero no logró identificar a que parte del proyecto o archivo del proyecto se refiere. Anexo captura de dicha exception.
[image: LogCat inicio de errores]

¿Algún consejo para poder ejecutar la aplicación?

---

Anexo el build.gradle en código como me solicitaron.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "venteks.villaavocadoandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }

    //fix to run aws libraries
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
    implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
}

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: Mira en el gradle si algún repositorio no es compatible. Otra opción es comentar todo el código, menos la del main. Luego descomentar varias porciones de código hasta que encuentres la línea que tiene el error.

Comment: Podrias compartir tu gradle para ver la estructura

Comment: Hola no ayudo mi respuesta a solucionar el problema?

Comment: no jorge, no ha ayudado tu aportacion, disculpa.